# jQuery .on("unload", fn) not working for me

Tags: jquery

I am trying to detect when the user leaves a page. I thought the .on("unload",fn) method should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on("unload", function(){
    alert("Goodbye!");
  });
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work. When I navigate away from the page nothing happens. If I change the "unload" to "load", however, the alert box shows appropriately when the page loads.

Is this the right way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
  }
</script>
```

Taken from https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm

"beforeunload" will be an event more reliable than the "unload" one, which seems to go deprecated. I also read that "beforeunload" event was more reliable when called from javascript than from jQuery

So in your case :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
      function confirmExit()
      {
        return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
      }
});
```

Comment: The live demo works but jQuery doesn't seem to know about the 'onbeforeunload' method. :(

Comment: You can write jQuery code in a javascript function (being carefull). To say it in another way, just attach this event with javascript and do your usual jQuery stuff beside.

Comment: Code added to fit your case.

Comment: Or if you wanted to do it in more of a jQuery style, you could do `$(window).on('beforeunload', function() { return 'Your message here'; });`. But it will work the same either way.

Comment: As long we don't use jQuery .bind(), it's ok. Good comment, so OP can stay in the jQuery syntax .